# How to inherit a pseudo-class properties?

Tags: less

I have a class that "extends" a class. I want it to also automatically extend "related pseudo-classes". What I mean by that:

Original class is

```
.original {
   property1: foo;
   &: before {
      property2: bar;
   }
}
```

New class is

```
.inheriting {
   .original;
}
```

I now want to `.inheriting: before` to have the same properties as `.original: before`. How do I do that in an easy way?

Comment: Well, yes you'll find some tips in the Q you linked above. Though for the particular code snippet you wrote above you *don't need* anything because `.inheriting` already *has* `:before` the way you wrote it (just compile your example to see its  CSS result).

Comment: Also note that `: before` is invalid CSS syntax, should be `:before` (or more standard strict `::before`).